# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I tried to add data to the database (using psycopg2.connect):

```
cand = Candidate('test', datetime.now(), 'test@test.t', '123123', "21", 'test', 'test', 'test', datetime.now(), "1", "1", 'test', 'M', "18", "2", "2")
db.addCandidate(cand)
```

my function adds:

```
def addCandidate(self, candidate):
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO candidate ( name, pub_date, email, tel, age, proff, href, city, last_update, called_count, status, comment, sex, recrut_id, vacancy_id, level)
              VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", (candidate.name, candidate.pub_date, candidate.email, candidate.tel,
                             candidate.age, candidate.proff, candidate.href, candidate.city, candidate.last_update, candidate.called_count, candidate.status, candidate.comment, candidate.sex, candidate.recrut_id,
                             candidate.vacancy_id, candidate.level))
        self.connection.commit()
```

I tried wrapping data in str, but nothing has changed.
in pymysql.connect works fine

Comment: What framework or library are you using to connect to the PostgreSQL DB? Do you get any error messages or warnings? What do you mean by "nothing has changed"? Did the DB content remain unmodified? Please try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: mysql and postgres don't act identically.  Perhaps one of your values is not a string?  Print out the result of your sql statement before you execute it.

Comment: Do you need to quote the datetime() results?

Comment: While I dont know python enough, do you not have a module that handles the need for quoting? i.e. what if one of the parameters have "Joe's outlet"? In .net framework, they do have OledbCommand and Parameters collection for example.

Comment: @joelgoldstick my statement: 'test', datetime.now(), 'test@test.t', '123123', "21", 'test', 'test', 'test', datetime.now(), "1", "1", 'test', 'M', "18", "2", "2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, I wrote 15 '%s', instead of 16

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure because I don't know the types of your columns but it's plausible that your datetime object is not of the right format. You're sending in the datetime object not a string in the right date format. Try:

```
candidate.pub_date.isoformat()
```

or

```
candidate.pub_date.strftime("<proper_format">)
```

See http://strftime.org/ for format options. That may work for you.

Comment: Thank you, I tried, I even tried to remove completely date in my statement, but I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

In instead of `execute` do `mogrify` to check what exactly is being sent to the server:

```
print cursor.mogrify ("""
    INSERT INTO candidate ( 
        name, pub_date, email, tel, age, proff, href, city, 
        last_update, called_count, status, comment, 
        sex, recrut_id, vacancy_id, level
    ) VALUES (
        %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s
    )""", (
        candidate.name, candidate.pub_date, candidate.email,
        candidate.tel, candidate.age, candidate.proff, candidate.href,
        candidate.city, candidate.last_update, candidate.called_count, 
        candidate.status, candidate.comment, candidate.sex, 
        candidate.recrut_id, candidate.vacancy_id, candidate.level
    )
)
```